# Should I bother for array type in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, image

I am trying to import a series of .tiff images in Python using the code below. I want to transform them intro arrays, so I can process the data. The problem is that, for some images that are signed integers 32 Bit, they are shown all white colour, and I don't recieve the proper matrix. 
What is a workaround here?
Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

img = mpimg.imread("filename.tif")
img_array = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.float)
plt.imshow(img_array,cmap=cm.Greys_r)
plt.show()
print(img_array)
```

Comment: I think is more a problem of `mpimg` than the conversion to float. The last one should work fine. Can you check `np.unique(img)` to see the values you get out from the loaded image?

Comment: I kept np.float and used np.unique on the img_array. this is the result: `[   0.    1.    2.    3.    4.    5.    6.    7.    8.    9.   10.   11.
   12.   13.   14.   15.   16.   17.   18.   19.   20.   21.   22.   23.
   24.   25.   26.   27.   28.   29.   30.   31.   32.   33.   34.   35.
   36.   37.   38.   39.   40.   41.   43.   59.   61.  255.]` Curiously, it has the 255 value, but my .tiff has a maximum value of 61

Comment: There is a huge jump from 61 to 255.. You can try something like `img_array[img_array > 70] = 70`. That will set all the pixels with 255 values to 70, which will enhance the contrast (just to check if it improves anything).

Comment: The equivalent (without manipulating the data, just for visualization) to the above would be to set `vmin=0, vmax=70` in the `imshow`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, but I will need to keep the matrix as it's returned, because I have different images with greater values than 61.

Comment: Can you upload a sample image to see why is not being visualized properly? It can be either the loader or the statistical nature of your data, but is hard to say whats going wrong without the image.

Comment: I cannot upload the image here, but I can upload it on a image hosting website. Is that allowed here (posting links)?

Comment: Yep I guess is ok. But I wont be able to have a look at it until tomorrow :p

Comment: I have it uploaded here: http://we.tl/UukjB45o6m Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded the image. Find below the conclusions:

```
from skimage import io
io.use_plugin('freeimage')
data = io.imread('/tmp/data.tif')
```

I use `scikits-image` for image analysis, but you can stick with matplotlib's built ins if you wish, there is no difference.

- Some basic statistics:

  ```
  >>> print(data.dtype, data.min(), data.max(), data.shape)
  int32 -2147483647 61 (4094, 6383)
  >>> print(np.unique(data))
  [-2147483647, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
   15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
   31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46,
   47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61]
  >>> print(len(np.unique(data)))
  46
  ```
- Trying to plot the image:

  ```
  plot(data)
  ```

[image]

So what is happening here? You have int32 data, with most of the values in the `[0, 61]` range, but the background of the image is hardcoded as `-2147483647`. That's why, when you try to plot something you see nothing but black and white. Internally, `matplotlib` is rescaling the grayscale range to your data (from `[0, 255]` to `[-2147483647, 61]`), and that's why all your foreground looks white: `[0, 61]` in `[-2147483647, 61]` is pretty much white.

What can you do to avoid this from happening?

**1- Visualize ignoring the background (the following results are the same image with different colormaps):**

```
    imshow(data, vmin=-1)  # <-1 values are set to -1, only for visualization
```

[image]
[image]

**2- Replace the background value in your data by some value higher or lower:**

```
    data[data < 0] = data.max() + 1  # or data[data >= 0].min() - 1
    imshow(data)
```

[image]
[image]

Later on you can convert your data to the type you want, and answering your original question: `float` should be perfectly OK (I mostly work with floating point images).

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well now. I kinda needed to work with floating point images and this solves it. :)

Comment: @Litwos glad it helped :) good luck with it! Btw if is not anything sensible, what is the data about? It looks quite interesting (and hard to analyse).

Comment: It's a canopy height model of a forested region, and I need to apply wavelet filters on it (gotta need a bit of help there as well :/ ). Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What kind of values are you seeing in the image array?

I notice that you're trying to show the image with Greyscale, if I'm not mistake. I'm pretty sure that grayscale is between 0-255 so try representing the array with np.uint8

Comment: Matplotlib's colormaps are scaled to the data (including grayscale), so there is no need for that.

Comment: If I use np.float, the values are like this: `[   0.    0.    0.  255.]
  [   0.    0.    0.  255.]
  [   0.    0.    0.  255.]]]` 
Using np.uint8 works, but got me thinking about "nodata" values, that are greater in size than int8 (they are int 32). Is that a problem?

Comment: @Litwos your data is getting clamped. All values above 255 are set to something else. Just try `np.uint8(500)`. If you want to convert it to uint8 you need to *rescale* your data to [0,255] before calling `.astype(np.uint8)`.

Comment: I need to keep the data as it is because I will perform further analyses. So I should conclude that by using np.uint8(500), the "nodata" pixels that have a value of -2*10^9 will become 255, thus, not needing to use np.float agai?